# Liferay ServiceUtil and LocalServiceUtil difference

Tags: java, web-services, liferay

What's the difference between these two utils? I can read about this question on official Liferay forums, but it is not quite clear to me. I can read parts of explanation anywhere, but what I need is an exact, complete and clear explanation what is the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Liferay, *local* services typically "just do the work", without any permission checks. That's why they're local - you can't access them remotely. (In fact, just as Pierpaolo states in the comments, they're only available from within the same JVM, e.g. from within the same appserver). The *remote* services (or just services) typically implement a very similar interface but do execute permission checks before they delegate their actual execution to the local services (or before they return the data to the caller).

Don't be distracted by the "remote" part of the service's name: You can also call them locally, they have a local java interface just like the local services. Only call the local services if you're sure that you don't want the permission checks. And it's best practice to implement permission checks in remote services...

Comment: As usual this is a great answer by Olaf. I just write to add a note, specifying that "local" term means "accessible only from the same JVM where they are available".

Comment: Thanks for the compliment - you're right, I didn't make this explicit. I'll edit it in.

Comment: @OlafKock: Can you please provide context for the sentence. "local services typically "just do the work", without any permission checks".

I'm eager to get your idea on "Permission Checks" thing..?? Are you depicting "Permission Checks" for resources to the Role ..???

Comment: Thank you and @ParkashKumar too for such a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

When generating liferay service layer through service.xml, there is option to control generation of local and remote service(s) via following attributes on entity:

`local-service="true"` represents `LocalServiceUtil`, which defines that your service layer is accessible locally in portlet / portal scope.

`remote-service="true"` represents `ServiceUtil`, which defines that your service layer can also be accessed from remote applications through web-services.